# How to deal with uncompilable source code in web app projects that need to be deployed for testing?

Tags: java, maven

I have a web app project under development using Maven 2 that I want to deploy on server to be able to *view the webpages for testing purposes while developing*. Howver there is also a lot of uncompilable code in the project because of which I am getting  `Compilation failure` errors while trying to build & package the project as war for deployment. How can I deploy such project with uncompileable classes, or better say,  how do I view my webpages while keeping aside the uncompilable java classes in the source packages of the project ?

---

*Using Maven 2 for a JSF2.0(facelets) project with Netbeans 6.9 & glassfish 3.01.*

Comment: Fix the compilation errors, and then deploy the project.

Comment: @JB Nizet : there are lot of errors in java classes  that i cant fix as of now... and since i m working on the webpages development rightnow, i need a way to view the webpages for testing purposes & dont need to anyhow use the uncompilable code..

Comment: actually i moved from a simple web app project to maven web app project . previously i could deploy an uncompilable project on glassfish.. i think the it deployed the webpages alone & not built the entire project but now in the maven project i am seeing that i *must* build the project before trying to view webpages

Comment: I guess that the Netbeans IDE allows you to run the project even if certain classes are uncompilable, then switch back to a simple web app project.

Comment: yes  exactly.. simple web app project` did helped me that way.. but now with maven, seems that there is no help on this..

Answer (score 3):

Check compiler plugin and compile mojo which is called during at compile phase. Default value for failOnError is true. You should make it false.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#failOnError

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <failOnError>false</failOnError>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

I think that this configuration will be enough.

Comment: an issue that i saw lately, after using your tip... even though the project was successfully deployed when there were errors in code but even if any one of the java class in the project was uncompilable, that lead to the entire java classes not being there in `/target/classes' folder but I saw the files being compiled in the console output while project was being building